# Why is the mongoDB c# driver getting intermittant error DnsClient.DnsResponseException: Header id missmatch

Tags: c#, mongodb, dns, .net-core

Intermittantly I get the following error from the MongoDB C# Driver running on dot net core. All queries fail for a few minutes complaining about DNS query errors and then after a few minutes it is fixed.

```
DnsClient.DnsResponseException: Header id missmatch.
   at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Audit continueAudit)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.Query(DnsQuestion question)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString.Resolve()
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl.Resolve()
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(MongoUrl url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the enterprise server backups (Asigra) were scheduled to run at the same times as we saw this error - moving the backups to a different time fixed the issue.